# ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [4194], [65], [51]

Tags: oracle, oracle-xe, ora-00600

I have issue on Oracle.

When I execute startup to open database there is error in alert log that ORA-00600: internal error code.

Oracle was working without issue and suddenly this issue is arose.

Oracle version is 10g express.

I just wonder if this issue can be happened when DBF file size is over 10G.

I added another datafile to the tablespace last week.

I wonder if express version can not add more datafiles.

**Could you please tell me what would be issue ?**

ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [4194], [65], [51], [], [], [], [], []

Comment: 10g Express Edition only supports 4GB.  If you want to get around that limitation you'll either need to buy something, such as personal edition, or upgrade to 11g express edition.

Answer (score 3):

> "I just wonder if this issue can be happened when DBF file size is
>   over 10G."

Oracle XE is free but comes with various restrictions.  In 10g the limit on User Data was 4GB [(citation)](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B25329_01/doc/install.102/b25143/toc.htm#BABIECJA) , although I would expect that limit to be enforced gracefully.  Does that total cover *all datafiles* i.e. including Undo and Temporary tablespaces?

"I added another datafile to the tablespace last week."

When you added that additional file did you breach that 4GB User Data limit?  Note that in 11g the User Data limit was raised to 11GB, so that would be a good reason for you to upgrade.  [Check it out](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17781_01/admin.112/e18585/toc.htm#BJFEIJGJ).

Anyway, ORA-00600 is Oracle's generic message which it throws whenever it encounters unexpected behaviour, i.e. an internal bug.  The usual advice for this is to contact Oracle Support but most XE users don't have Support contracts.  In which case there is the Oracle TechNet forums, which include a site dedicated to XE issues.  [Find it here](https://forums.oracle.com/community/developer/english/oracle_database/oracle_database_express_edition_%28xe%29).

There should be more information in the Alert Log.  You can find the Alert Log in the background dump directory.  If you don't know where that is, locate it in SQL*Plus

```
 SQL>  show parameter background_dump_dest
```

The chances are this is probably a corruption issue.  You'll be fine (provided you have been doing proper back-ups) as Oracle's recovery utilities are pretty good.  [Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B25329_01/doc/admin.102/b25107/backrest.htm#i1004902).

Answer (score 0):

```
ORA-600 [4194] "Undo Record Number Mismatch While Adding Undo Record"    
VERSIONS:
    versions 6.0 to 10.1
    DESCRIPTION:
    A mismatch has been detected between Redo records and rollback (Undo)
    records.
    We are validating the Undo record number relating to the change being
    applied against the maximum undo record number recorded in the undo block.
    This error is reported when the validation fails.
    ARGUMENTS:
    Arg [a] Maximum Undo record number in Undo block
    Arg [b] Undo record number from Redo block
    FUNCTIONALITY:
    Kernel Transaction Undo called from Cache layer
    IMPACT:
    PROCESS FAILURE
    POSSIBLE ROLLBACK SEGMENT CORRUPTION
```

You'd better restore your undo tablespace from rman backup ,it may fix this problem.  If any backup is unavailable , then PRM-DUL (an Oracle Recovery/Rescue Tools ) can be your last resort .

Answer (score 0):

First make the copy of table which creates problem. rename the table original table and then duplicate table to be given the name of original table.Then run query it will work.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this error during PL/SQL development using **TOAD**. I  opened a new session and the error disappeared!

Comment: I had the same error code when I tried to update a function. The change is very minor but I saw this error using an old DB connection. After open a new connection, the update went through.